# PCMan File Manager automount permissions

Tags: fedora, ntfs, file-permissions, automount

Having some trouble with PCMan and USB automounted file systems.

My USB is NTFS so it won't let me change permissions on the files.

Is there anyway i can configure the way PCMan automounts the plugged in USBs?

Comment: did you ran Pacman Daemon to automount removable media? `pcmanfm -d`

Comment: @Ravi no it seems to be setup out of the box to simply automount all usb drives that are plugged in.